# F# - How to conveniently apply elements in a list to a curried function's parameters?

Tags: f#

Supposed there is a list:

```
let lst = [1;2;3]
```

And a curried function:

```
let addAll a b c =
   a + b + c
```

How can I input the parameters for the curried function *coveniently* using the elements in list `lst`?

One way of doing this is:

```
addAll (lst |> List.item 0) (lst |> List.item 1) (lst |> List.item 2)
```

But this doesn't scale very well! Also, it's boring.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do what you are asking.  If you are applying the same operation throughout, the usual way to handle this would be to do a fold on the list.  I'm thinking this might be a case of the [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) [Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Is there something in particular you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say from the limited example what your actual use case is. Lists are designed to contain a varying number of items and functions take constant number of items, so the two do not match well. It might make more sense to use a tuple rather than a list:

```
let tup = (1,2,3)

let addAll (a, b, c) =
   a + b + c

addAll tup
```

Tuples contain fixed number of items, but they can be easily constructed and deconstructed and allow you to pass all parameters to your function at once.

You can also do what you asked about using reflection, but this may break in future versions of F# and it is almost never a good design for a simple case like this. It is also slow and as you can see from the number of downcasts and boxing, it is also not very safe:

```
let lst = [1;2;3]
let addAll a b c =
   a + b + c

let addAllVal = addAll
let f = addAllVal.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke", [| typeof<int>; typeof<int>; typeof<int> |]) 
let res = f.Invoke(addAllVal, Array.map box (Array.ofList lst)) :?> int
```

Comment: Reflection is a good starting point to address such problem dynamically. We can just write a utility function to wrap all Reflection code, then use it elegantly elsewhere. However, as you suggested, reflection can be slow...

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use pattern matching:

```
let lst = [1;2;3]

match lst with [ a ; b; c] -> addAll a b c |_-> 0
```

returns `6`.
If lst does not have exactly 3 elements then it returns `0` but you can change it to handle other cases:

```
let callAddAll lst =
    match lst with 
    | [              ]      ->            0
    | [ a            ]      -> addAll a 0 0
    | [ a  ; b       ]      -> addAll a b 0
    | [ a  ; b  ; c  ]      -> addAll a b c
    |   a :: b :: c :: rest -> addAll a b c  // ignore rest

[       ] |> callAddAll |> printfn "lst = %d"  // = 0
[1      ] |> callAddAll |> printfn "lst = %d"  // = 1
[1;2    ] |> callAddAll |> printfn "lst = %d"  // = 3
[1;2;3  ] |> callAddAll |> printfn "lst = %d"  // = 6
[1;2;3;4] |> callAddAll |> printfn "lst = %d"  // = 6
```

Comment: Definitely another option. But it is still manual like my approach.